# Drop pandas rows based on percentage of valid data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame that looks like this

| Date_Time | level |
| --- | --- |
| 2018-02-12 13:22:27 | 5 |
| 2018-02-12 13:17:27 | 7 |
| 2018-02-12 13:12:27 | 2 |
| 2018-02-12 13:07:27 | 6 |
| 2018-02-13 13:12:27 | 4 |
| 2018-02-13 13:17:27 | 5 |

How do I make it so If there is less than 3 entries on a specific date they get removed
i.e since 2018-03-13 < 4 entries remove them and get this table

| Date_Time | level |
| --- | --- |
| 2018-02-12 13:22:27 | 5 |
| 2018-02-12 13:17:27 | 7 |
| 2018-02-12 13:12:27 | 2 |
| 2018-02-12 13:07:27 | 6 |

I tried using a for loop but that takes too long to run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) with `count` and then use [`ge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) to get the rows you wanted:

```
df[df.groupby(df['Date_Time'].dt.date)['Date_Time'].transform('count').ge(4)]
```